# Dynamical Systems course by Stefano Luzzatto.

Tags: dynamical-systems

I'm looking on youtube the fantastic course of Stefano Luzzatto called ["Dynamical Systems"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DoNV15RWijE&index=2&list=PLLq_gUfXAnkmC-VWIJ_HW8cdOZLEtHfXJ).

He always mention that some exercises are left as homework. 
Does anyone have those **homework sets of questions**? I would like to do his exercises because it's a very good course.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1kf9js8aiehvlml/ErgodicTheoryIntro.pdf?dl=0

Comment: Are you after the text of the exercises, or some solutions sheets?

Comment: I want to try the exercises. Definitively I'm not looking for a solution sheets.

Comment: @HeMan: Why not email the presenter and ask him directly?

Comment: I already have done that.

Comment: Hi. It's the second course from ICTP I've been following. Did you manage to find the sheet?